# How do I get this to refer to the React component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a video component class that possesses a `handleRecord` method. Inside the `handleRecord` method, there's an object called `recorder` which returns a blob the object method call called `stopRecording`.

Whatever gets returned, I want the value to set state in the video component. But the `this` refers to recorder object in the callback, not the component itself. What's best practice to get the component within the callback and use the `recorder` object?

```
handleRecord() {

    ...

    } else {
        this.state.recordVideo
        recorder.stopRecording(function() {
            var blob = this.getBlob(); 
            console.log(this) // <= this refers to recorder object not the component
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a variable to refer to the component, then use it inside the function:

```
const component = this;
recorder.stopRecording(function() {
    var blob = this.getBlob(); 
    console.log(component); 
});
```

This will essentially capture the `this` value when *it does refer to the component* and cache it in `component`, so when you use it in the callback function `this`'ll refer to the recorder object, but `component` will refer to your component.

Of course, you *could* just directly refer to the `recorder` object if you would like to use something like an arrow function, which takes the `this` value of its enclosing scope -- which is the component:

```
recorder.stopRecording(() => {
    var blob = recorder.getBlob(); 
    console.log(this) // <= this refers to component
});
```

Comment: Interesting approach.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I think I like the second approach the best. Check for this.